# ¿Ayuda como pasar a una vista un query en MVC 5 sin generar migracion?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, web

Hola a todos estoy trabajando en un proyecto en MVC 5 con las migraciones de Data Entity, genere una tabla pero ahora a ese mismo proyecto quiero hacer un query de otra tabla ya existente, un `SELECT` y enviar los registros como tabla a una vista, pero no modificar nada de la estructura de la tabla, la cual ya tiene registros. Abajo les dejo mi código.

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MvcMovie.Models
{
    public class Municipios // clase nombrada igual que la tabla ya existente la cual no fue generada con migraciones
    {
        public int ID { get; set; } // nombrados igual que las columnas
        public string Municipio { get; set; }

        public string Estado { get; set; }

    }

    public class MunicipiosDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Municipios> Municipios { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
 private MunicipiosDBContext db = new FormularioDBContext(); 
// GET: /Movies/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Municipios.ToList());
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Proyecto.Models.Municipios>// aquí tengo problema cuando quiero agregar dos tablas al mismo tiempo,una generada por migraciones que es un archivo, y su clase, y el otro que les muestro aquí, no se la sintaxis para agregar los dos modelos que son archivos separados en models. EN esta view ya muestor unos inputs con valores de la tabla generada por las migraciones, pero tambien quiero mostrar los registros de una tabla generada en sql en esta misma view

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}


@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>

         <th>Municipio
               </th>

         <th>Estado
               </th>


        </tr>
        <td>

          <td>id=item.Municipio</td> 
       <td>  id=item.Estado 
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te mal interpreto, lo que quieres hacer, (recibir dos modelos) no es posible, para eso se utiliza el concepto de `ViewModel`, para que se entienda, voy a usar un ejemplo.

Yo tengo 2 clases.

**A**

```
   public class a

    {
        public string propiedad_1{ get; set; }
        public string propiedad_2{ get; set; }
    }
```

y **B**

```
   public class b

    {
        public string propiedad_3{ get; set; }
        public string propiedad_4{ get; set; }
    }
```

Si yo quisiese enviar ambos 4 campos a una vista, ya sea para presentarlos como una tabla, o no, lo que debería hacer sería un `ViewModel`, que sería una clase como la siguiente

```
   public class VMayb

    {
        public string propiedad_1{ get; set; }
        public string propiedad_2{ get; set; }
        public string propiedad_3{ get; set; }
        public string propiedad_4{ get; set; }
    }
```

Luego por último, en el controlador, realizaría la lógica para guardar la información que requiero en mi `ViewModel` (`VMayb`)

Por ejemplo,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var lista_a = db.a.ToList();
    var lista_completa = new List<VMayb>;
    foreach(var a in lista_a)
    {

     lista_completa.propiedad_1 = a.propiedad_1;
     lista_completa.propiedad_2 = a.propiedad_2;
     lista_completa.propiedad 3 = "otro valor" //Podrías obtener los valores del lugar donde los necesites.
    }
    IEnumerable<VMayb> ListaFinal = lista_completa;
return View(Lista_Final);

}
```

Luego en la vista, bastaría como recibirlo como

```
@model IEnumerable<Proyecto.ViewModels.VMayb> //o cualquiera sea la ruta donde
//hayas creado la clase.
```

Espero que sea lo que andabas buscando, saludos!